# for loop closes parent div

Tags: php, html, for-loop

I have a PHP for loop that inserts HTML. Here is the code:

```
<div class="half-col full" align="left" data="evts">
    <?php

        for($i = 0; $i < count($evts); $i++) :

    ?>

    <li class="<?php echo ($i==0)?"selected":"";?>">
        <div class="date">
            <li class="cell">
                <span><?=$evts[$i]["month1"]?></span>
                <?=$evts[$i]["day1"]?>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="cell">
                <span><?=$evts[$i]["month2"]?></span>
                <?=$evts[$i]["day2"]?>
            </li>
        </div>
    </li>

    <?php

        endfor;

    ?>
</div>
```

The problem is that this loop inserts 3 `<li>s`, but after the first `<li>` is inserted, the parent `<div>` is closed, so the source ends up looking like this:

```
<div>
    <li> <!--Inserted-->
</div>
<li> <!--Inserted-->
<li> <!--Inserted-->
```

Is there a way to prevent the parent `<div>` from closing before all 3 `<li>s` are inserted?

Comment: I'm not a friend of using `for(..): endfor;` and always close and reopening the php tag to insert html. I think it provides more issues than you think this is readable. Yes it does work, but if there is sometime somewhere an issue you don't know where it comes, it maybe is from that behavior.

Comment: an `<li>` should be inside `<ul>` or `<ol>`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Yeah this is the first time I have tried to implement this type of loop, but it seemed most appropriate here.

Comment: Give us the html source code which gets actually printed (only the important part).

Comment: @Coderanonymous Since using `{ }` doesn't change the broken html source code, it won't make any difference.

Comment: yeah i figured that out later, sorry for being silly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<li>` must be inside `<ul>`, `<ol>` or `<menu>`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li

Compare the output source code and the website's DOM. The weird result should be caused by a browser trying to fix the broken source code.

Comment: Ah I see. I've gotten into the bad habit of using <li>s wherever I want to list anything in block style format. I'll have to teach myself to put a <ul> in there too.

Comment: Or just use replace `<div>` tag with `</ul>` to keep your structure slim and maintainable: e.g. `<ul class="half-col full" align="left" data="evts">` and `<ul class="date">`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<div class="half-col full" align="left" data="evts">
  <ul>
    <?php

        for($i = 0; $i < count($evts); $i++) :

    ?>
    <li class="<?php echo ($i==0)?"selected":"";?>">
      <div class="date">
        <ul>
          <li class="cell"> <span>
            <?=$evts[$i]["month1"]?>
            </span>
            <?=$evts[$i]["day1"]?>
          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li class="cell"> <span>
            <?=$evts[$i]["month2"]?>
            </span>
            <?=$evts[$i]["day2"]?>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <?php

        endfor;

    ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant! So the only problem was that it wasn't in a <ul>? Or was there something else you changed?

Comment: Actually `<li>` should always be kept inside `<ul>` or `<ol>`. Nothing else changed in your code :)

Comment: I wish I could accept you both, as you both answered my question at about the same time. Simon just got to it a *little* bit quicker :P but I did upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should put your second div tag outside the li tag somthing like this

```
<div class="half-col full" align="left" data="evts">
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i < count($evts); $i++) :
?>
<div class="date">
    <li class="<?php echo ($i==0)?"selected":"";?>">
        <li class="cell">
            <span><?=$evts[$i]["month1"]?></span>
            <?=$evts[$i]["day1"]?>
        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="cell">
            <span><?=$evts[$i]["month2"]?></span>
            <?=$evts[$i]["day2"]?>
        </li>
    </li>
</div>

<?php
    endfor;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is only due to mismanagement of html tags like `<li>` without necessary tag. It may cause many problems so, first solves these issues. There is not any problem in the loop but only with html tags.

Answer (score -1):

```
          </li>
    </div>
</li>

<?php

    endfor;`
```

your `</div>` is inside the loop. Move the closing tag outside the loop and your problem is solved :)`

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The loop is closing the outermost <div>.